# How can I know my fit is good?

Tags: statistics, regression, regression-analysis

I have some data and I realize a fit by myself but according to me the fit is not good at all... the problem is I would like to have a formula which tell me if the fit is good or not... I precise I fit data using Bessel functions. Thank you for your help !

Comment: No I have some data that I fit with bessel functions and I just want to check if my fit is good or not.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine if a fit is good or bad if you do not first express what means "good" and "bad" on mathematical form.

Thus, you have to chose a criterion of fitting which allows to compute a value which is a measurement of the goodness of fit between the set of observed values and the values expected under your model (That is the formula involving Bessel functions).

First, chose a standard test which underlying measure of fit appears convenient in your case. They are a lot :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit